# Unknown file extension ".jpeg" while converting Image to base64 string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

I am trying to convert a `jpeg` image to base64 image in nodejs. I am using the following code:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import catImage from '../public/cat-image.png';

export const getImage = (path) => {
    try {
        const image = fs.readFileSync(path, 'base64');
        return image;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return null;
    }
}

console.log(getImage(catImage));
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".jpeg"
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong with this code? I am new to Node.js.

I tried `.png` instead of `.jpeg` but to no avail. Thanks for helping.

Comment: you can't `import` from an image file. You just want `const catImage = '../public/cat-image.png';`